# XCode PhoneGap Project Build Error

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova

I am trying to build a phonegap project in XCode but every time I build, it gives "No architecture to compile error...". I read I need to setup target first for IPhone simulator, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is add "i386" to your Valid Architectures option in XCode. This is located in your build settings. You might also try deleting the armv6 and armv7 settings and then re-adding them with "$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)".